# Variation of entropy in a transference of heat

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

When we put two bodies with different temperatures in contact, there will be a heat transference between them. The variation of the entropy of the system is well known (this is computed in most physics textbooks). However, I was thinking: in the beginning, when we put the bodies in contact, the total system will not be in a thermodynamic equilibrium, so it does not make sense to talk about the entropy of the initial state. After a time, the system will be in equilibrium, so we can define a final entropy, but not an initial one. So, I think we can't talk about the variation of the entropy of the system. It's like asking "what is the variation of the temperature of the system?" In the beginning, the system does not have a definite temperature. As we can ask what is the variation of the temperature of each of the bodies, but not of the total system, we can compute the variation of entropy of body 1 and body 2, but not of them together. What's wrong with this thought?

Comment: The initial state of the two body system is when the bodies are not yet in contact with one another. The assumption is that, prior to bringing the bodies into contact with one another, they are each in thermodynamic equilibrium internally. Therefore, the initial entropy of the two bodies is the sum of the entropies of the two bodies prior to contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial state is a composite system made by two subsystem each one at equilibrium. Entropy is an additive quantity: the entropy of the composite system is the sum of the entropy of each subsystem. Notice that the situation is different for temperatures: temperature is **not** an additive quantity and it is meaningless to add temperatures of each subsystem as well as there is not a temperature which can be considered a property of the combined system.

After creating a thermal contact, the system reaches a final equilibrium state. The entropy of that state is a well definite concept, exactly like the entropy of the original composite system.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately before we put the bodies in contact, the system is in a thermodynamic equilibrium, so it has a well-defined entropy. The final state also has a well-defined entropy, as you note. We can use the difference between these values to define $\Delta S$. This does not require that we define $S$ at every intermediate time.

Comment: But, to it be true, the entropy of a system composed by two non-interacting subsystems should be equal to the sum of the entropies of each subsystem. Why is it true? To me, it makes more sense says that the total entropy of the system is a function of position: when we are in the body 1, $S = S_{1}$, and when we are in body 2, $S = S_{2}$. However, in ths case the variation of the entropy would be equal to the variation of the entropy of one of the bodies, what is not true.

Comment: It seems like you are thinking of an intensive analogue of entropy, which is defined locally. However, in this context the entropy we usually talk about is an extensive quantity, defined only globally. What you suggest is like saying that the mass of the system is $m_1$ when we are in one body, and $m_2$ when we are in the other - a statement like that would make sense for density, but it doesn't make sense for mass.